VS Code Error: file not recognized: File truncated collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

PS D:\Coding> cd "d:\Coding\AP" ; if ($?) { g++ exp_Graph.cpp -o exp_Graph } ; if ($?) { .\exp_Graph } c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a: file not recognized: File truncated collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status PS D:\Coding\AP>

I expect every code to give output, but unexpectedly this error showed up. Earlier it was all okay. I don't know how it is appearing like this.

What g++ version are you using? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit version? Also, please do not add unrelated language tags. If you use g++, you are programming in C++ and that is a very different language than C.

Sounds like either a broken toolchain installation, or a misconfiguration of VS Code.

If the error suddenly started appearing, then you have to think back to what you were doing just before you saw this error. Clearly this problem is related to some setting you changed, or something you installed, or some other environmental change.

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/ means you didn't follow the official VSCode MinGW instructions and instead have a very old version of MinGW installed. The official documentation is here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
